Direct proof of Hasse bound for j=0 case via $\Delta(p,q) = -3u^2$
Is it possible to prove the Hasse bound for elliptic curves in the $j$ invariant 0 case by directly deriving $\Delta(p,q) = -3u^2$ where $$\Delta(p,q)=\Delta(q,p)=(p+1-q)^2-4p \ge -4\min(p,q).$$
Hasse bound is the assertion $\Delta(p,q)\le 0$.
Intuitively "equalities are easy" and "it is the inequalities that require ingenuity" but I cannot derive the $\Delta(p,q)=-3u^2$ equality at all.
Where would one start with to prove anything like this? The fact that we're expressing 4p as $a^2 + 3b^2$ and Eisenstein integers being UFD seems very interesting but still can't make much progress.

I think I made some progress with Fourier analysis on $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ i.e., Fourier analysis on p-1 elements.
